# Access VBA - recordset losing position

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

Option Compare Database
    Private rs As Recordset

```
Private Sub Send_Click()
Dim strLocation As String

 If MsgBox("Please confirm you wish to run todays tasks.", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If


Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
Debug.Print rs("title")

    'Call Update_Progress("Test", rs("ID"))

rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hello,

Please see the code above.
Can someone advise how I keep the recordset's position when I move between functions/subs.

This code loops through the records fine if I note out the "Update_Progess" Function but when this is in, it continually loops through the first record?

thanks in advance

Comment: This should work. Can you reduce the code of Update_Progress as much as possible *while still showing the problem* ("minimal reproducible example") and add it to your question? (You can use the "edit" link below your question for that.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, once I knew it should work I checked the functions, I had a Requery in there which was causing the issues, I have changed to a Refresh and it is working. I shouldn't have assumed it was the sub I guess, my bad

Comment: Well done, congratulations on fixing it! I suggest that you copy your comment into an answer and "accept" it, so that the question no longer shows up as "unanswered".

Comment: done and done, cheers

Answer (score 1):

As in the Comments,

I had a requery of the form in one of the Functions which was causing the recordset reset its position, this was fixed by amending to a refresh.